# Repaint() isn't working and I don't know why

Tags: java, image, swing, repaint

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Core game = new Core();
    game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    game.frame.setTitle("Multiply");
    game.frame.setIconImage(testIcon);
    game.frame.add(game);
    game.frame.pack();
    game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    game.frame.setResizable(false);
    game.frame.setVisible(true);

    t1.start();

    new Core().run();
}

public Core(){
    KeyListener listener = new MyKeyListener();
    addKeyListener(listener);
    setFocusable(true);

    Dimension size = new Dimension(width, height);  //variable that sets the size of the window to 1280x720p
    setPreferredSize(size);                         //Sets the size of the window to "size" 

    frame = new JFrame();                           //makes frame into the JFrame window
}


public void run(){
    running = true;
    loop();
}

public void render(){
        repaint();
        System.out.println("runnin");
}

private synchronized void loop(){   //Running loop, while the game is open this will always be running
    long lastLoopTime = System.nanoTime();
    final int TARGET_FPS = 60;
    final long OPTIMAL_TIME = 1000000000 / TARGET_FPS;
    int fps = 0;
    long lastFpsTime = 0;

    while(running == true){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        long updateLength = now - lastLoopTime;
        lastLoopTime = now;
        double delta = updateLength / ((double)OPTIMAL_TIME);

        lastFpsTime += updateLength;
        fps++;

        if (lastFpsTime >= 1000000000)
          {
             System.out.println("(FPS: "+fps+")");
             lastFpsTime = 0;
             fps = 0;
          }

        enemyAI();
        render();

        try {
            Thread.sleep( (lastLoopTime-System.nanoTime() + OPTIMAL_TIME)/1000000 );
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void enemyAI(){
    if(menu != true){
        enemyX++;
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void paint(Graphics g) {        // Draws top first to bottom last 
    super.paint(g);
    String imagesString = "C:/Users/BigBertha/Desktop/Multiply_Game_Engine/";
    Image background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imagesString+"Images/Green_Background.png");
    Image character = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imagesString+"Images/Character.png");
    Image enemy = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imagesString+"Images/Enemy.png");
    Image inDevText = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imagesString+"Images/InDevText.png");

    Image menuScreen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imagesString+"Images/MainMenu.png");
    Image menuArrow = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imagesString+"Images/MainMenuArrow.png");
    //Image loadingScreen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imagesString+"Images/LoadingScreen.png");

    if(menu){
        g.drawImage(menuScreen, 0, 0, 1290, 730, this);

        if(menuAPos1){ //play
            g.drawImage(menuArrow, menuArrowX1, menuArrowY1, 125, 100, this);
            loading = true;
        }
        else if(menuAPos2){
            g.drawImage(menuArrow, menuArrowX2, menuArrowY2, 125, 100, this);
        }
        else if(menuAPos3){
            g.drawImage(menuArrow, menuArrowX3, menuArrowY3, 125, 100, this);
        }
            g.drawImage(inDevText, width - 95, height - 20, 100, 40, this); //removed eventually
    }
else if(running){
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 1290, 730, this); //draws the black background
        g.drawImage(inDevText, width - 95, height - 20, 100, 40, this); //removed eventually
        g.drawImage(character, charX, charY, charSizeX, charSizeY, this); //draws the character
        g.drawImage(enemy, enemyX, enemyY, enemySizeX, enemySizeY, this);
}
}
```

I need the `loop()` method to be able to run `repaint()` but it does nothing when it's called. I've tried many different variations to try and get it to work but nothing has worked. I've been thinking about using JOGL but i need to complete at least a decent amount of a game prototype for school.

Answer (score 4):

1. Your use of `synchronized` is possibly causing the freeze. Since the `run` method never releases the monitor, `paint` can't be entered. Instead of [`Thread.sleep(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) (which does not release a monitor) you could try [`wait(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait-long-) (which does release a monitor).

   ```
   try {
       wait( (lastLoopTime-System.nanoTime() + OPTIMAL_TIME)
                   / 1000000 );
   } ...
   ```

   But you should really consider whether synchronizing the whole `run` method is necessary. It could cause frame rate problems if the game loop is not waiting often enough.
2. It's unclear where you are starting the thread for `game` if you are starting one at all... (This might also cause the problem 'does nothing' which you are seeing.)

   ```
   Core game = new Core();
   ...

   t1.start();

   new Core().run();
   ```

   `new Core().run()` creates a second, unrelated instance and calls its run method directly on the main thread. You should instead be doing something like `new Thread(core).run()`. (Is that what `t1` is?)
3. You shouldn't be loading images inside `paint` (the calls to `Toolkit.getImage`). Doing this means you are loading each file every frame. You should load your resources *once* in to a class or instance field.
4. We generally don't override `public void paint(Graphics)` in Swing programs, we override `protected void paintComponent(Graphics)`.

Also see

- [*Synchronization*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)
- [*Defining and Starting a Thread*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)
- [*Painting in AWT and Swing*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [*Lesson: Performing Custom Painting*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)